# Parcelable interface persist the object reference? & Parcelable.CREATOR is not called?

Tags: android, android-fragments, parcelable, parcel

I am using Parcelable interface to pass my objects into fragments. According to Android's documentation, it's an "interface for classes whose instances can be written to and restored from a Parcel"[[1]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).
I was expecting that everytime when the ParcelableObject is passed into another fragment through Bundle, the object is written into Parcel and then the Parcelable.CREATOR should recreate the object and initialize the object's variables.
Here comes a little surprise for me, if I put my parcelable object (X) into Bundle and set this bundle as an argument for my new fragment. Then I read my parcelable object (Y) from bundle in onCreateView method of the new fragment. The object I get in onCreateView (Y) is identical with the one (X) I have put into Bundle in the previous fragment (meaning X == Y). Even more surprising is that, the Parcelable.CREATOR is not even called.
They write in Android's docu about Bundle: "A mapping from String values to various Parcelable types." [[2]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). So ok that's maybe what explains why is the written object identical with the read one, but why they need the Parcelable.CREATOR interface when it works as correct even without it ?

Let's be more concrete now:

I have a `ParentPagerFragment`, which contains a ViewPager and it's a parent for 3 `ChildTextViewFragment`

Here is the important part of `ParentPagerFragment` impl.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container, false);

    List<ChildTextViewFragment> viewFragments = new ArrayList<>();

    MyEntity mEntity1 = new MyEntity();
    mEntity1.setId(1l);
    MyEntity mEntity2 = new MyEntity();
    mEntity2.setId(2l);
    MyEntity mEntity3 = new MyEntity();
    mEntity3.setId(3l);

    viewFragments.add(ChildTextViewFragment.newInstance(mEntity1));
    viewFragments.add(ChildTextViewFragment.newInstance(mEntity2));
    viewFragments.add(ChildTextViewFragment.newInstance(mEntity3));

    MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), viewFragments);

    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    return v;
}
```

The `ChildTextViewFragment` only displays a simple `TextView`

`ChildTextViewFragment::newInstance implementation`

```
public static ChildTextViewFragment newInstance(MyEntity mEntity) {
        ChildTextViewFragment fragment = new ChildTextViewFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        Log.d(MyEntityParcelable.TAG, "ChildTextViewFragment::newInstance : creating Parcelable : mEntity has ID = "+ mEntity.getId() +" mEntity = " + mEntity);
        MyEntityParcelable entityPar = new MyEntityParcelable(mEntity);
        bundle.putParcelable(M_ENTITY_KEY, entityPar);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }
```

`ChildTextViewFragment::onCreateView implementation`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text, container, false);

        TextView mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        MyEntityParcelable mEntityPar = getArguments().getParcelable(M_ENTITY_KEY);
        MyEntity mEntity = mEntityPar.getMyEntity();
        Log.d(MyEntityParcelable.TAG, "ChildTextViewFragment::onCreateView : reading Parcelable : mEntity has ID = "+mEntity.getId()+" mEntity = " + mEntity);

        mTextView.setText("my id is: " + Long.toString(mEntity.getId()));

        return view;

    }
```

MyEntity:

```
public class MyEntity {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String owner;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }




}
```

MyEntityParcelable

```
public class MyEntityParcelable implements Parcelable {

    public static final String TAG = "PARCELABLE_TESTING";

    private MyEntity myEntity;

    public MyEntityParcelable(MyEntity mEntity) {
        this.myEntity = mEntity;
    }

    private MyEntityParcelable(Parcel in) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MyEntityParcelable::Parcel constructor : creating MyEntity from Parcel");
        myEntity = new MyEntity();
        myEntity.setId(in.readLong());
        myEntity.setName(in.readString());
        myEntity.setDescription(in.readString());
        myEntity.setOwner(in.readString());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return this.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MyEntityParcelable::writeToParcel : writing myEntity with ID =  " + myEntity.getId() + " to Parcel");
        dest.writeLong(myEntity.getId());
        dest.writeString(myEntity.getName());
        dest.writeString(myEntity.getDescription());
        dest.writeString(myEntity.getOwner());

    }

    /*
     * Parcelable interface must also have a static field called CREATOR, which
     * is an object implementing the Parcelable.Creator interface. Used to
     * un-marshal or de-serialize object from Parcel.
     */
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyEntityParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyEntityParcelable>() {
        public MyEntityParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyEntityParcelable(in);
        }

        public MyEntityParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyEntityParcelable[size];
        }
    };

    public MyEntity getMyEntity() {
        return myEntity;
    }

}
```

As I mentioned above the PARCELABLE.CREATOR is not even called, here is the Log demonstrating the control flow.

```
13:55:14.946: ChildTextViewFragment::newInstance : creating Parcelable : mEntity has ID = 1 mEntity = com.example.nestedfragments.MyEntity@21208247
13:55:14.951: ChildTextViewFragment::newInstance : creating Parcelable : mEntity has ID = 2 mEntity = com.example.nestedfragments.MyEntity@1ecfc4f8
13:55:14.952: ChildTextViewFragment::newInstance : creating Parcelable : mEntity has ID = 3 mEntity = com.example.nestedfragments.MyEntity@3c4a9dd1
13:55:15.069: ChildTextViewFragment::onCreateView : reading Parcelable : mEntity has ID = 1 mEntity = com.example.nestedfragments.MyEntity@21208247
13:55:15.071: ChildTextViewFragment::onCreateView : reading Parcelable : mEntity has ID = 2 mEntity = com.example.nestedfragments.MyEntity@1ecfc4f8
13:55:33.614: ChildTextViewFragment::onCreateView : reading Parcelable : mEntity has ID = 3 mEntity = com.example.nestedfragments.MyEntity@3c4a9dd1
```

Please note that the object identities are the same at creating and reading.

Is this a correct way to pass objects between fragments ? 
In which cases is the Parcelable.CREATOR interface called ?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 4):

> So ok that's maybe what explains why is the written object identical with the read one, but why they need the Parcelable.CREATOR interface when it works as correct even without it ?

Your `Parcelable` is not being put into a `Parcel`, and so the `Parcelable.CREATOR` is not used.

A `Parcel` is involved with IPC. So, if you tried passing the same `Intent` extra via `startActivity()`, that would involve your `CREATOR`, as `startActivity()` involves IPC.

A configuration change *might* involve a `Parcel` (they may optimize this scenario). If your process is terminated while in the background, and the user quickly returns to your running task via the recent-tasks list, that will involve a `Parcel` and a `CREATOR`.